# How to import a module statically within a dynamically loaded module

Tags: python, import, dynamically-generated

I am dynamically loading filters to my app. Now I want to be able to extend existing filters:

In my Main.py I do:

```
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(filter, file)
inst = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(inst)
```

I have a file called varianceFilter.py that loads and runs fine:

varianceFilter.py:

```
def run(images):
    #do something
    return result
```

Now I want to reuse and extend this filter like so:

testFilter.py:

```
import varianceFilter as vf

def run(images):
    ret = vf.run(images)
    #do something with ret 
    return ret
```

However as soon as I try to import varianceFilter.py the exception

```
No module named 'varianceFilter'
```

is thrown. both files are in the same directory. 
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

My directory structure is:

```
main.py 
filters/varianceFilter.py
filters/testFilter.py
```

After creating a copy of varianceFilter in the main directory, testFilter.py works fine.

Comment: What exception? The full error message including the full stack-trace is almost always extremely helpful for debugging.

Comment: Thanks juanpa, I've updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the empty file

```
filters/__init__.py
```

and changing the import statement in testFilter.py to

```
import filters.varianceFilter as vf
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: You should think carefully about how you're doing this.  From your question it looks like you are loading modules outside the normal import mechanism.  Your solution works for the files you showed, but if you try to import a "plugin" from some other location, you'll likely have the same problem again.

Comment: BrenBarn, thats true. However, the restrictions you trade against a nice structure are not that hard: Once the containing directory ("filters") is not renamed one can freely move it around.